# Is it possible to boot from both USB and SD-card

Tags: usb, boot, sd-card

After following [official USB boot instruction](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md) I was able to write `program_usb_boot_mode=1` to OTP and boot from USB. But it looks like am not able to boot from SD-card anymore. Are these options mutually exclusive?

**Edit:**
I have a model `Pi 3 Model B` and by *mutually exclusive* I mean that after enabling USB boot one no longer is able to boot via SD-card.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are mutually exclusive and the change is permanent.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md

Answer (score 1):

No. (Although this depends on what you mean by mutually exclusive - booting or setting OTP bit.)

You don’t say which model Pi you have; the instructions to set the OTP bit only apply to the Pi3.

The OTP bit is set by default on the Pi3B+ (as `vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 17:` shows) but it boots from SD Card if no device is detected within 5 seconds.

Comment: This is applicable on both 3b and 3b+ model